# NullPointerException,nothing is null

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send some data to Activity B from Activity A.
code of Ytadapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView != null){
        mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }else{
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
        mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_favorite);

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    //Setting the data
    final SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

    //Loading the image
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

    //OnClickListeners
    mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppUtils.showToast(result.getSnippet().getTitle() + " Was added to favorites.");
            m.sendResult = result;
            m.sendToFavorites();
        }
    });
```

Initializing in YtAdapter:

```
    private Activity mActivity = null;
private List<SearchResult> mVideoList = null;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
```

This is the code of A:

```
public void sendToFavorites(){
        Intent fav = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Favorites.class);
        fav.putExtra("title",sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle());
        fav.putExtra("thumbnail",sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl());
        fav.putExtra("id", sendResult.getId().getVideoId());
}
```

This is the problem I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

According to the IDE, The problem is in the MainActivity in the line 
Intent fav = new ...

Comment: Please show whole implementaton of listener or anything that sends the data.

Comment: @Blackbelt is it possible? I do not use Context context or something like that .

Comment: the stacktrace says so. Can you post the complete stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @DawidBugajewski sure, first of all, a little background, I have a view which as ImageView, when this Image is clicked, I'm calling to MainActivity m; m.sendResult = result and m.sendToFavorites, sendResult is not null.

Comment: You will also get the line number of occurrence from the [LogCat](https://muthumanict.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/debugging-using-logcat/).

Comment: @Blackbelt I added the YtAdapter. the problem seems to be in Intent fav = new ...

Comment: the problem is this line: `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();`

Comment: Okay, I thought so too, so.. how can I access MainActivity from YtAdapter without having this problem? maybe not add new MainActivity(); ?

Comment: `new Intent(MainActivity.this` > `MainActivity.this` is null (the context it provides) in this place in the code. Look at the source code for new Intent(Context and you will see where it does `context.getPackageName`

Comment: @Blundell can you give me please an example how should I create the MainActivty m so It won't be null ? I think I got your answer and I will try it, but I want example too, in case It was not what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: `m.sendToFavorites(mActivity);` > `public void sendToFavorites(Context context){ Intent fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);` . You should never ever new up a class that extends Activity, also just use the instance that the Android framework gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never ever new up a class that `extends Activity`, use the instance that the Android framework gives you.

`new Intent(MainActivity.this` > `MainActivity.this` is `null` (the context it provides) in this place in the code.

Look at the source code for `new Intent(Context` and you will see where it does `context.getPackageName`

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#L4160
leads to:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/ComponentName.java#L64

To fix this you need to use the correct context (Activity)

change your method call to

`m.sendToFavorites(mActivity);`

and your method to

`public void sendToFavorites(Context context){ 
    Intent fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);` .